# How to hide minutes li here in css

Tags: html, css

I have below html code with List items. Here I don't want 'Minutes' list item so I want to hide it. How can I hide this item using CSS. I mean override this style in external css file

```
<div class="y-dropdown larger open">
   <div class="placeholder"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Daily</a></div>
   <ul class="items" style="display: block;">
      <li><a href="#0" class="daily">Daily</a></li>
      <li><a href="#0">Weekly</a></li>
      <li><a href="#0">Monthly</a></li>
      <li><a href="#0">Quarterly</a></li>
      <li><a href="#0">Yearly</a></li>
      <li><a href="#0" class="minutes">Minutes</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: To overwrite css we can use "!important", but remember that its not good practice, avoid  as much as possible.
.minutes{
       display:none !important
}

Comment: `.items li:last-child { display: none; }` or `.items li:nth-child(6) { display: none; }` or `ul.items > li.minutes { display: none; }` etc......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add CSS `display:none` for `minutes` like

```
li.minutes{
  display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have to overwrite some CSS properties you have to give `!important` to that property.

Here,

```
ul.items li.minutes {
  diaplay: none!important;
}
```